# Euler-Mascheroni Constant and the Digamma Function

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence, proof-writing, gamma-function, euler-mascheroni-constant

I have been trying to prove without success that the digamma function evaluated at $1$ is equal to the Euler-Mascheroni constant $\gamma$.

I would like to know if there is any way of doing it by just assuming the following facts:

- the definition of the gamma and of the digamma functions;
- the Bohr-Mollerup Theorem;
- $\Gamma(x) = \lim \limits_{n \to \infty}\left(\frac{n!n^x}{(n+x)\cdots(x)}\right)$, $x>0$;
- $\gamma = \lim \limits_{n \to \infty}\left(\sum_{1}^{n}1/n - \log n\right)$.

My attempt so far consisted in noticing that the Eulero-Mascheroni limit can be recovered by taking the logarithmic derivative of the limit definition of gamma. However, I have not been able to prove uniform convergence around $1$, which would have been enough to justify swapping limits or using results on convergence of the sequence of derivatives.

---

As always, any comment or answer are much appreciated and let me know if I can explain myself clearer!

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leonhard_Euler . You use the Italian spelling ;-)

Comment: @PaulFrost Thank you for pointing that out!

Comment: You could use the Weierstraß representation for the gamma function. Though I confess the only ‘elementary’ proof I have seen of this identity played fast and loose with convergence, and the Weierstraß factorisation theorem itself is advanced

Comment: @FShrike Thank you very much for the answer! I have asked for an elementary solution because I have read somewhere that what I have assumed in my question should be enough provided one manages to interchange limits, which is exactly my problem.

Answer (score 1):

Get the power series for $\log\Gamma(1+x)$ using the (provided) definition of $\Gamma$ and the [discrete DCT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tannery%27s_theorem), and then take the derivative at $x=0$ (which becomes a trivial step). Writing the definition as $$\Gamma(1+x)=x\ \Gamma(x)=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n!\ n^x}{(1+x)\cdots(n+x)}=\lim_{n\to\infty}n^x\prod_{k=1}^n\frac{k}{k+x},$$ we get, for $|x|<1$,
\begin{align}
\log\Gamma(1+x)&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left[x\log n-\sum_{k=1}^n\log\left(1+\frac xk\right)\right]
\\&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left[x\log n+\sum_{k=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^\infty\frac1j\left(-\frac xk\right)^j\right]
\\&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left[x\left(\log n-\sum_{k=1}^n\frac1k\right)+\sum_{j=2}^\infty\frac{(-x)^j}{j}\sum_{k=1}^n\frac1{k^j}\right]
\\&=-\gamma x+\sum_{j=2}^\infty\frac{(-x)^j}{j}\zeta(j),
\end{align}
with the last line by Tannery (i.e. discrete DCT).